# how to let .htaccess to get a value and make a redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I asked this question before and watched many tutorials but I'm not getting this working !!

I want to redirect "website.com/alex" (that doesn't exist) to "website.com/template.php?user=alex" and to hide all extensions of all files on server "php, html, etc.."

what should I write into my .htaccess

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can redirect all your request to your `index.php`
and you will handle it easy and this will remove all extensions `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this redirects everything that doesn't exist to template.php, I also want to get the value written in the link to handle it, for example "website.com/alex" , I want to get "alex" to do the appropriate call from the database, and so on ...

Comment: you can handle your link by getting it from `$_SERVER` super global object

Comment: yes, good idea.. Thanks a lot .. I'll come back to you after I try all this

Comment: you are welcome :), i will add it as answer

Comment: ok, one last question, why do I get permission error after adding the .htaccess file ! at the beginning it worked , after restarting the pc, I couldn't access the server "no permission" ... The .htaccess content is exactly the same as u guided me ..

Comment: if it worked before it should worked now, i recommend you to write new question with the new problem but before that please accept my answer if it help you

Comment: Surely accepted, I didnt before because I'm new to stackoverflow and I didnt know these details.. 
let's see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it easier by redirecting all your requests to your `index.php`
by adding these lines to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

after that, you can now easily handle your `url` and get what you want from `url` by
using `$_SERVER` superglobal variable